# Connect to non-local ActiveMQ with AJAX

Tags: ajax, activemq-classic

I am new to activeMQ. I have some javascript that connects to amq to get/put messages:

```
function init()
{
//AMQ message handler
amq.init({ 
    uri: amqURI, 
    logging: true,
    timeout: amqTimeout,
    clientId:amqClientID
});
amq.addListener(amqName, amqTopic, amqHandler);
}

function amqHandler(message)
{
alert("message");
}

function amqSend(content)
{
    amq.sendMessage(amqTopic, content);
}
```

This works fine if the webpage is served on the same machine as the queue (i.e. using localhost:port/amq or machinename:port/amq in the uri) - however connecting to a queue on another machine just gives me a timeout.

I have setup jetty.xml to include:

```
<bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
        <property name="port" value="8161" />
</bean>
```

and web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/amq/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have even tried adding to activemq.xml:

```
<transportConnector name="websocket" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614"/>
<transportConnector name="nio" uri="nio://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
```

But still no luck connecting to the remote activeMQ.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like normal Ajax restriction for cross domain requests. The restriction is in the browser and prevents any XmlHttpRequest to be sent to other domains than the site was loaded from.

There are some ways around this restriction, such as using the [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) pattern. However, it will not solve the problem you have (since it supports HTTP get, but not HTTP POST, and both addListener and sendMessage does this).

You  might want to think of putting up a proxy or something that can pipe the data correctly, server side. But it's not that trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are calling Ajax from Javascript outside a browser (or a browser that restricts JS in some way).  After much experimentation we figured out that the problem was the servlet insisting on authentication, but since there was no browser to pop up a window, it failed.

I disabled authentication in jetty-demo.xml and voila--it worked!

See the section entitled: Securing Web Console on [this page](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html) for how to do it.